# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000013). Click OK to close the application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I suddenly had [this problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/3dfba1eb-fd7d-4a06-95e6-deddf6abf8eb) when starting up my (previous *boots*) working VS 2010 project.

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000013). Click OK to close the application.

Debug output:

```
`The program '[5940] myapp.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741805 (0xc0000013).`
```

Comment: Voting to close since the OP figured out their (unrelated) issue.

Comment: [See meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) about answering your own question.  The purpose is to park the info here, so others can find it.

Comment: That's true if the issue you had is applicable to anyone else; in this case, I really don't think it is.

Comment: Interestingly, see the other answers posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

STATUS_NO_MEDIA_IN_DEVICE, "There is no disk in the drive".  Your debugging working directory is probably set to a USB emulated disk that's unavailable.

Comment: Answer of the YEAR!! You're absolutely right. I enabled USB storage on the phone and the problem doesn't appear.

Comment: Poor guy in that linked thread re-installed his entire operating system.  Ouch.

Answer (score 4):

I suddenly had the same problem with projects under VS 2008 after some Windows updates. But upon reading this thread I've decided to check %PATH% and found that some paths referred to locations on an empty DVD drive. Fixing the paths solved the problem. (In the end, updates seem to be unrelated, the only thing that matters is that media was ejected from the device after restart.)

Answer (score 1):

Remarkably I unplugged my charging Android 2.3 and it worked.

Comment: This is the strangest solution ever to this problem. Are you sure it's actually related? `:S`

Answer (score 0):

I had error STATUS_NO_MEDIA_IN_DEVICE and the issue turned out to be a missing debug DLL, I had to add a build step to copy it over.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be due to conflicting DLL versions, to find out if this is the case, one can use the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), with a [step-by-step tutorial by Code Yarns here](https://codeyarns.com/2010/07/01/dependency-walker/). In my case it was because the program was 32-bits and the required libraries were 64-bits, where it expected 32-bits.